# ransack search multiple children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ransack

I am using ransack gem for filtering. I've got a Link model with a has_many :tags relationship.

I've created a control that allows for multiple select of the tags, and I want to display all results that match all tags chosen.

If I do :link_tags_tag_id_in, the query just returns any link that has at least one of the tags in the selection. I am trying to figure out how to return only links that contain all tags in selection.

Thanks in advance!